# Xamarin.Forms 4.6 using the LibVLC library on Android crashes when Play method is called

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono

I am using Xamarin.Forms 4.6 and the LibVLCsharp library to show videos on Android devices.
I ran some of the sample apps and got a couple to run but those sample apps are using Xamarin 3.2.

The problem is as soon as the Play method is called the app crashes hard and doesn't even throw an exception.

I get this in the output window:

06-19 12:37:29.044 D/ViewRootImpl@cb7f4a7MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0
06-19 12:37:29.113 D/ViewRootImpl@cb7f4a7MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 1
06-19 12:37:29.128 D/Mono    (10562): DllImport searching in: 'libvlc' ('libvlc.so').
06-19 12:37:29.128 D/Mono    (10562): Searching for 'libvlc_media_player_play'.
06-19 12:37:29.128 D/Mono    (10562): Probing 'libvlc_media_player_play'.
06-19 12:37:29.128 D/Mono    (10562): Found as 'libvlc_media_player_play'.
06-19 12:37:29.129 D/Mono    (10562): DllImport searching in: 'libvlc' ('libvlc.so').
06-19 12:37:29.129 D/Mono    (10562): Searching for 'libvlc_media_player_get_media'.
06-19 12:37:29.129 D/Mono    (10562): Probing 'libvlc_media_player_get_media'.
06-19 12:37:29.129 D/Mono    (10562): Found as 'libvlc_media_player_get_media'.
Thread started:  #11
06-19 12:37:29.166 D/Mono    (10562): Requesting loading reference 5 (of 11) of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.xamarintestapp/files/.**override**/LibVLCSharp.Forms.dll
06-19 12:37:29.166 D/Mono    (10562): Loading reference 5 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.xamarintestapp/files/.**override**/LibVLCSharp.Forms.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
06-19 12:37:29.166 D/Mono    (10562): Assembly Ref addref LibVLCSharp.Forms[0x7ab54d3e80] -> Java.Interop[0x7a9f22e800]: 14

=================================================================

## Native Crash Reporting

Got a SEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

## used by your application.

No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).

=================================================================

## Basic Fault Address Reporting

Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7a90c94e68):0x7a90c94e58  20 8b 46 f9 ff 03 00 f9 e1 83 00 91 22 00 a0 72   .F........."..r
0x7a90c94e68  08 00 40 f9 33 00 a0 72 08 19 40 f9 00 01 3f d6  ..@.3..r..@...?.
0x7a90c94e78  a0 03 00 34 28 a9 00 b0 20 8b 46 f9 08 d9 1a 91  ...4(... .F.....
0x7a90c94e88  00 e4 00 6f 00 1d 08 4e f3 0b 00 b9 e0 03 81 3c  ...o...N.......<

## ===================================================

## Managed Stacktrace:

domain required for stack walk=================================================================
06-19 12:37:29.167 W/.xamarintestap(10562): 0xebadde09 skipped times: 0
06-19 12:37:29.170 F/libc    (10562): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 10643 (Thread-17), pid 10562 (.xamarintestapp)

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?  I attached a sample test to this post which demonstrates what I am seeing.
A link to the test app is here:  http://www.filedropper.com/xamarintestapp2

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/353

Answer (score 1):

Missing Core.Initialize() call